# moving button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are `next` and `prev` buttons in the slideshow, that I want they move a few pixels and change their colors after clicking on these buttons. The button returns to the normal position by removing the mouse. Although I know I can coding with CSS, but it is part of my homework and I have to do that with javascript. This is my code but it doesn't work and I don't know why ...

```js
function press() {
    document.getElementById(this).style.right = "-10px";
    document.getElementById(this).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(1)" onmousedown="press()">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(-1)" onmousedown="press()">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: is jQuery available?

Comment: @mahroo you should pass attribute id value to the `getElementById()` not `this`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to the function, then you have the element directly.

```js
function press(element) {
    element.style.marginRight = "-10px";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<a class="prev" onmousedown="press(this)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onmousedown="press(this)">&#10095;</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function applyStyles(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  element.style.fontSize = '18px'
}

function revertStyles(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  element.style.fontSize = '15px'
}
```

```html
<span onclick="applyStyles(this)" onmouseleave="revertStyles(this)">&#10094;</span>
<span onclick="applyStyles(this)" onmouseleave="revertStyles(this)">&#10095;</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The native function `getElementById` only accepts a string as parameter, that must be the "id" of the html element you want to iterate with. Your code should be something like this:

```
function press(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.right="-10px";
    document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="red";
}


<a id="prev" class="prev" onmousedown="press(this.id)" >&#10094;</a>
<a id="next" class="next" onmousedown="press(this.id)">&#10095;</a>
```

You too can make it directly changing only your js function by passing this as function parameter:

```
function press(htmlElement){
    htmlElement.style.marginRight="-10px";
    htmlElement.style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Comment: Why would you get the `id` from the element (`this`) and then use `getElementById` with the extracted `id` to get the element again?!